# Using onscreen.click() in turtle but only works at the end of the programme

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

This is the programme I wrote but I'm not sure what's wrong:-

```
import turtle
import random

bob = turtle.Turtle()
screen = turtle.Screen()

def coord(x,y):
    print(x,y)
    turtle.onscreenclick(None)

turtle.onscreenclick(coord)
turtle.listen()

print('hello')
turtle.done()
```

The programme works fine except that the print('hello') part happens first, followed by the on screen event. How do I make the onscreen event occur first before the rest of my programme?

Comment: `listen` is for keyboard events.  Presumably, your hitting <Enter> to kick off the program via command line is consumed as the event and execution passes to the `print('hello')`.  How are you executing your program?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make the rest of your code part of the `coord` function:

```
def coord():
    print(x,y)
    turtle.onscreenclick(None)
    print("Hello")
    # The rest of your program goes here.
```

However, a few things to note:

- This isn't an amazing elegant solution, especially if you intend to set up other events further into your code. It can become quite hard to keep track of.
- It's imperative that you remove the event binding (in this case the binding of `coord` to `onscreenclick`) as soon as it's been used, otherwise you could end up with multiple instances of the same code running at once if someone double-clicked the screen, for example. In your case you've already done this (with `turtle.onscreenclick(None)`), but it is something to keep in mind.
- If you choose to go this route, don't forget to rename the `coord` function something more representative of what that section of your code will do.